# How to replace the thousand separator and keep other commas in Python or VBA in Excel

Tags: python, excel, regex, vba

I have a column named 'policy' with rows of data like this:

> media A,type A,2019-08-29 to 2019-12-31,0.00 CNY ≤ amount ≤
> 10,000,000.00 CNY, 10.50%, --;media B,type B,2019-08-29 to
> 2019-12-31,0.00 CNY ≤ amount ≤ 10,000,000.00 CNY, 10.50%, --;

It's a combination of field values separated by commas.

Now I want to replace all the thousand separators within the numbers like '0.00 CNY ≤ amount ≤ 10,000,000.00 CNY'.
I tried to use regex to replace them:

```
df['policy'].replace(to_replace=r'(?<=\d{1,3})\,(?=\d{3})', value='', regex=True)
```

but Python raises an error says 'look-behind requires fixed-width pattern'.

I hope I can get results like:

> media A,type A,2019-08-29 to 2019-12-31,0.00 CNY ≤ amount ≤
> **10000000.00** CNY, 10.50%, --;media B,type B,2019-08-29 to 2019-12-31,0.00 CNY ≤ amount ≤ **10000000.00** CNY, 10.50%, --;

Since the digit of the number is uncertain, i.e., it could be 1,000.00, 10,000,000.00, or 999,999.00, I can't write fixed-width pattern. I wonder whether there is a way to replace them in Python or probably some kind of VBA script I can run in Excel.

Any ideas would be fine, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The number of digit before the first comma you want to replace doesn't matter.

A regex like `(?<=\d{1})\,(?=\d{3})` should be able to find all the commas you want to replace.